# i can't get elements out on integer array that exists in string.xml

Tags: java, android

i have an array that exists in string.xml which is contains some images ids you can find dowen here in this picture how i'm tring to get this ids out but somehow the app Crashes and doesn't show anything in the logcat
[MainActivity.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMKIT.png)
[string.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKyLe.png)

Comment: check logcat tab. It should has error displayed there.

Comment: "<=" is probably one issue (in the for loop) - should be "<".

Comment: Please copy and paste the code in question without external links.